# Updating view in VueJS when calling filter method by click

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to re-render my view in vuejs whenever i click on a checkbox. I'm filtering the data with a method before rendering the view and that works fine. What doesn't work is updating the view on click. Below is the code with some console logging i used to check so that the if statement works but i'm not sure if the array of data is updating.

```js
const storeListVm = new Vue({
        el: '#stock-status',
        data() {
            return {
                stores: []
            };
        },
        computed: {
            orderedStores: function() {
                return this.stores.sort(compare);
            },
            inStockStores: function() {
                return this.stores.filter(function(store) {
                    return store.stock;
                });
            }
        },
        methods: {
            showOnlyInStock: function() {
                return this.stores.filter(function(store) {
                    console.log($('.js-stock-only:checked').length);
                    if ($('.js-stock-only:checked').length) {
                        console.log('trigger in stock');
                        return store.stock;
                    } else if(!$('.js-stock-only:checked').length) {
                        console.log('trigger no stock');
                        return store;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<section id="stock-status">
<span class="stock-status__search-opts--count" v-cloak>({{inStockStores.length}})</span>
<input type="checkbox" class="visually-hidden js-check-input js-stock-only"         checked hidden v-on:click="showOnlyInStock">
<div class="store-list" id="store-list">
  <div class="store-list__store" v-for="store in showOnlyInStock(orderedStores)"      :key="store.id"></div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: You can try look at vue dev tools, what is in array and there is no good reason to use jQuery with vue js

Comment: Remove jQuery, remove showOnlyInStock. Make filteredStores a computed property that filters the array accordingly. Bind the checkbox value to your model with v-model="showOnlyInStock" (boolean, not function).

Comment: Lifesaver, thanks a lot! Worked with a computed property and v-model